# Show user names (and maybe avatars) on "accounts" tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, linked-accounts

The old "accounts" tab showed the flairs, hence included avatars and user names. Since March 25th, this now pulls the view from Stack Exchange.

I assume names and avatars are simply not shown on the Stack Exchange layout, as that information is redundant for *most* users? Still then: the names are even stripped from the URLs, so are really hidden.

Could we please at least see the user names in the URLs?

(I liked being able to see the names, especially on MSO when folks have a different display name on MSO only, or change it on MSO quite often. And sometimes it helped finding semi-sockpuppets, but that is hardly a good reason to keep them around I guess.)

Comment: I do rather miss being able to see all of Grace's different avatars

Comment: +1. It was a nice overview of which username I used on which site.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative: what about showing [the user card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work), with its  avatar, when hovering a site's name?

(That would not work for all users, but for some active users it would.)