# How does the User Card popup work?

Tags: discussion, user-card

We are experimenting with enhanced user card mouseover popups and have enabled them network wide. You can tell which users will trigger the popup because they have a 3-D drop shadowy look to their gravatar:

[image: hover example]

**Hover your mouse over the gravatar** and wait. Note that the user card mouseover popup will *only* be displayed if the following conditions are met:

- Is the profile complete, and long enough? We enforce a minimum length requirement.
- The user's reputation must be >= 1k
- If you have more links than are able to be displayed after truncation, those extra links will be shown in the bottom of the dialog. We order links at the bottom consistently -- if you include a twitter, google plus, linked in, or facebook those links are prioritized.
- It will be visible on a question and answer detail page, any page with a list of questions, and the /users list.
- It will not be shown when a question or answer is wiki'd.
- It will not be shown when excerpt summary is defined as `<!-- summary: &nbsp; -->`
- we support explicitly specifying your user card excerpt summary using the following syntax:

  `<!-- summary: This is my profile, there are others like it but this one is mine. -->`

The above example will result in:

[image: hover]

This is now mostly complete.

The goal is allow people to show  off how awesome they are inline, without having to click through to the full user profile page.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the 'last seen' time in the card too.  I find I'm often clicking through to check this when deciding whether to flag or edit a post.

Comment: @martin - That doesn't seem like it fits with the rest of the information presented above. I see "business-card-like" data, not administrivia (however useful) like "date last seen".

Comment: I really like the profile summary feature. I'd second adding the last seen data to the popup, it would help us determine how likely a user is to come back and fix an old post without having to click through.

Comment: @Michael - I agree in principle.  I'd been planning to check whether there was a feature request to make 'last seen' available without click through to the profile page.  If it doesn't sneak in on these cards, I'll do that instead.

Comment: @martin I am pretty deeply opposed to that as it runs counter to the philosophy of the main site. On chat, of course, it is essential and already present there all over the place.

Comment: I know, small detail, but: lots of kudos for not fetching the larger avatar until the popup is shown, and meanwhile showing the low resolution avatar!

Comment: @Jeff I can live with the click-through.  You mean we want people assessing posts on the basis of their content, rather than on when or by whom they were posted?  That makes sense when the viewer is an Answerer, but when you're an Editor, or looking to clean up noisy comments, you need a slightly different set of information to make the right call.

Comment: When I added social links to my profile description I am not getting the nice spacing shown in your example above. What's the markdown look like to accomplish that?

Comment: @ahsteele I have edited your profile so you can see an example.

Comment: @Geoff thanks didn't realize the summary made the difference, thanks!

Comment: Can you make this tagged as FAQ?

Comment: Does it take time to generate the popup after an edit, or something? I just changed mine and now can't see it on any site, even when logged out.

Answer (score 13):

Is it possible to put links in the excerpt summary? If not, please consider this a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: unfortunately no.  HTML or markdown inside of an HTML comment isn't supported.  If you want links edit About Me to include them.

Comment: It's kind of unfortunate that they can be included in the automatically-generated summary but not a tailored one.

Answer (score 7):

Nice feature! Both useful and looking nice.

My two cents: add preview in the user profile when member view his own profile.. currently to see my own card I need to visit one of my questions or answers.

Comment: You might be interested in [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105094/add-user-card-preview-to-profile-editing-page).

Comment: Nice, didn't see it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Could we make the user card also appear when hovering over the person's name?

I find hovering over the avatar less natural than hovering over the name. Supporting both might help people discover this feature.

Comment: You really better start a feature request for this, 8+ years later, I doubt feedback is still expected here.

Comment: ... good point.