# What's with the drop-shadow on certain gravatars?

Tags: support, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User card work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-work)

I just noticed a new drop-shadow effect on certain Gravatars.

It makes my profile image look a little silly (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921091/error-c2059-syntax-error/6921098#6921098) of mine).

I've also noticed that it's not applied to every Gravatar -- see the profile images of [this random question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278626/javascript-to-java-applet-communication) I looked at.

So... what was the rationale behind this drop-shadow? What controls when it appears?

Most importantly, is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: See [How does the User card work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810)

Comment: Aha, thanks for pointing out what I was missing :-)

Comment: Wait -- a second ago I had a drop shadow, but no user card. Then I re-saved my profile (without making changes), and now I don't anymore!

Comment: @Cameron: There is a way to turn it off. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/let-me-decide-whether-i-see-user-cards-and-gravatar-shadows