# Why is my display picture 3D while some others are 2D?

Tags: support, profile-page, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)
>   [What’s with the drop-shadow on certain gravatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104823/whats-with-the-drop-shadow-on-certain-gravatars)

[image]

As you can see there is a small projection for some pictures and not all. On what basis is the distinction made by SO? I thought it could be a matter of normal profile picture vs auto-generated (identicons), but no as you can see in the markings I have made in the picture embedded. I'm just curious...

Comment: If you hover over the "3d" ones, you'll see a mini user card pop-up showing some of their profile information. This is available (and enabled by default) for users with at least 1000 reputation.

Comment: @JeremyBanks thanks for the correct link. Its hard to search without knowing the key words. Voting myself to close this thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user (privilege earned at 1k rep). Specifically:

> #### How do people see an expanded usercard?
>
> When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on
>   the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded
>   usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a
>   *hover card*.
>
> [image: Comparison of normal usercard and expanded usercard]
>
> An expanded usercard is only available if you have have at least 28
>   characters in their "About Me" section of their profile. You can tell
>   if your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard if there
>   is a drop shadow effect shown on your avatar.
>
> [image: Image of drop shadow versus normal]
>
> #### What information is shown on the expanded usercard?
>
> Your expanded usercard will show the following information:
>
> - A larger resolution of your **avatar**
> - Your **display name** linked to your profile
> - Your **reputation and badges**
> - Your **Location**, if you have entered one on your profile
> - A **link to your Website**, if you have entered one on your profile
> - Your **About Me** section. Up to the first 298 characters will be displayed as the meat of your expanded usercard. HTML links and
>     linebreaks/paragraphs will be rendered, but not formatting such as
>     bold.
> - Any **additional HTML links** will be displayed and linked at the bottom of the expanded usercard. This does not repeat any links that
>     are already shown in the previous part.

Comment: Je ne suis pas forcément un grand amateur de nouvelles technologies mais parfois c'est quand même bien pratique surtout quand il s'agit de services 3D (http://www.priximprimante3d.com/assistance/), je viens par exemple d'imprimer une pièce d'échappement de ma moto grâce à une imprimante spécialisée.