# Style of Gravatar icon display changed on StackOverflow

Tags: support, gravatar, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User card work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-work)

Why has the style of the Gravatar icon display changed for SO, and why is it inconsistent?

An example can be seen in [Javascript to Java Applet communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278626/javascript-to-java-applet-communication/7278780#7278780).

[image: Gravatar icons on SO]

Note that the first two icons have a shadow, while the 3rd does not.

( If you're accepting votes, I vote for no shadow.  My Gravatar has transparency and is designed to blend in with the page - excepting for the huge letters of my initials in red/orange smack dab in the middle of it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the question [How does the User card work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104810/141346) for a full explanation but essentially users with a reputation >= 1000 have a user card popup available which is indicated by the shadow.

Comment: OK.  Your answer (thank you) explains the image.  But on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278757/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-in-the-undecorated-frame), mKorbel (7985 rep) is not showing the shadow/card.  Shouldn't the card be available for them?  Is it because they have not filled in biographical data (beyond location)?

Comment: @Andrew: This is answered in the linked question, but yes, there is a minimum length requirement.

Comment: @hammar:  My bad - missed that detail.  I blame the brain (which isn't working at full capacity today).  :P