# Drop shadow around avatar doesn't look good on avatars with transparency

Tags: discussion, support, user-card

[image]

Notice how there's a shadow [under my avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264022/adding-md5-to-a-uitextfield/7264082#7264082)?  Now I know this shadow comes from the recent addition of the "[user card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)".

However, it just doesn't look good on some avatars.  Is there no way around this for people with alpha-transparency in their avatars?

Comment: Solution: stay below 2k rep ;-)

Comment: That won't be an option. ;)

Comment: Or empty your bio. Seriously, I agree that it just doesn't look nice on some avatars.

Comment: @Chi: Aaah ... with an empty bio, you won't get a user-card?

Comment: @Joachim You mean 1k?

Comment: @Jason: indeed, I mis-remembered the cutoff value.

Comment: @Don: indeed, the bio must contain *some* text. I see however on your tex.se profile which contains only an image that you got the dropshadow, but not the card. There's some bug here as well :)

Comment: I don't know anything about the web design techniques used here, so this is a blue-eyed suggestion: Would it be possible to adapt the shadow according to the outline of the picture with transparency? So that e.g. in sudo's current picture, it wouldn't display the white frame but instead cast a shadow around the right and bottom edges of the round-cornered square in his pic?

Comment: @doncherry: Unfortunately that's not possible with the current specifications of CSS.

Comment: @Chichiray: I don't have an empty bio on my SO user account.  I just haven't filled it in with my other accounts.  Fix'd.

Comment: Slightly related: [How far will you get with a 'rm -rf /'](http://superuser.com/questions/312769/how-far-will-you-get-with-a-rm-rf) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: Ha!  I've actually never used it myself.  I've been content with videos about it. :)

Comment: @sudo rm -rf: There is a way to turn it off. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/let-me-decide-whether-i-see-user-cards-and-gravatar-shadows

Answer (score 7):

You think you're unhappy?

I've got *two shadows*.

Comment: There is a way to turn it off. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/let-me-decide-whether-i-see-user-cards-and-gravatar-shadows

Answer (score 5):

Hum I think this would indeed be problematic for some user.

If I may try a suggestion, maybe we should change the background colour of the usercard (instead of adding a shadow) for people with profiles?

Comment: How does that fix the problem with the not alpha-transparency-honoring-shadow?

Comment: @Strait because you remove the shadowing. The problem is not the color but the shadow am I right.

Comment: Now I get you! Remove the shadow, change color instead. Now I understand.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it should indeed be changed. It's a minor detail, but "breaks" the elegance of many users' avatars.

Personally I now avoid getting a description precisely because of that :(

Just look at the [top users here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all): Jeff, Bill the Lizard, Robert Harvey, Popular Demand, and many more, all have avatars with white or transparent background which are sort of "broken" by this change.

Comment: There is a way to turn it off. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/let-me-decide-whether-i-see-user-cards-and-gravatar-shadows

Comment: @Saul very cool, but unfortunately this is "client side" - so everything will look fine to me but the elegance of my avatar will be still ruined for others :)

Comment: You missed the +5 comment by Hendrik Vogt. To fix your gravatar for others use `<!-- summary: &nbsp; -->`

Comment: @Saul very cool, but this disables the user card completely.

Comment: Yeah, that's the downside.