# What is the requirement for the pop up box on the user flair?

Tags: discussion, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

I have 1000+ rep in one of the SE, and I've add something inside the "About" section, but when I move my cursor over my flair, nothing happens. What is the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Your profile needs to be significantly longer. A single line is not enough, unless you fill in the special user card excerpt summary.

> Is the profile complete, and long enough? We enforce a minimum length requirement.
>
> see: [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)