# How can you get a hovercard on your username?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

I've noticed some users have a nice hovercard effect on the avatars that appear on their answers/questions.

What's up with that and how can one get such a nice hovercard?

From my observations, it seems users with over 2000 rep get them, but I'm not sure. It's just that everyone with high rep seems to have one, while users with 1k or less never.

I've looked on the [stackoverflow privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) and found nothing on that and neither did a search on "hovercard" or "profile" here, on meta, revealed anything useful.

Also, is this a network-wide feature?

Comment: you mean like this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user

Comment: ah, yes, sorry :D I only read the alt description, I didn't think there was more to that. Can you post that as an answer, please?

Comment: You need 1000+ rep and "displayable" contents in profile summary. Details are explained here: **[What is the requirement for the pop up box on the user flair?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106237/what-is-the-requirement-for-the-pop-up-box-on-the-user-flair)**

Comment: @Lix the one I pointed is better (**much** better) at explaining the requirements than "master question". I wish duplicate questions (and especially their answers) would be merged at MSO faster than now (1000x times slower than closing would be great) but unfortunately this isn't the case...

Comment: well, this is also an "what this is", not only what are its requirements. Still, it embarrasses me to see that there other questions like mine. This is a sign that I should read more than just the main page of the FAQ in the future and also visit the sub-pages/detailed sections

Comment: Never mind hovercards. Where's my [hoverboard](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzd1m6zshR1qc7jsy.jpg)?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[How do people see an expanded usercard](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) ?**

For usercard privilege you requires atleast 1K reputation.

When anyone is viewing your usercard on a question, an answer, or on the users list, they may hover over your avatar to produce an expanded usercard that contains extra information. This is also known as a **hover card**.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer after the required 5 mins