# User Profile (Mousover) ignores <strike> HTML

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, profile-page

I don't know if this is by design or not, but Stack Exchange accepts [basic HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) in almost every thing you can write. I found out that I had a < strike > tag in my "Bio" and that isn't properly displayed in the "hover popup".

Here's the text I have when I edit my profile:

```
I use Apple hardware and Mac OS X since the age of dawn but work doing <strike>C#.NET Windows Programming inside VMWare/Parallels</strike> Android development using Eclipse and the Android SDK.
```

And this is how it looks:

[image]

The Strike tag is ignored.

Of course it's not ignored in the [profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115/martin-marconcini) page.

Shall I remove that or is this a bug (or a feature)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design we support very limited markup in the summary; if you want the summary to have different text, [we allow you to do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work).  Strike-through is a prime example for that functionality.