# Could StackExchange Benefit From Link Currency?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, user-card

When someone posts a question or answer there is a link to their profile. What would happen if people with enough reputation were also given an additional link to their website? Just a small little link named "user site" or something as a sort of link-currency thank-you for using our site.

Answer (score 8):

User cards *already* support this.

[Established users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) (those with 1k+ reputation) have a 'popout' user card, and links are included in that:

[image: user card]

You can try it 'live' by mousing over my avatar to the bottom right of this post.

See [How does the User Card popup work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work) for more details.

Comment: I have used this site for years and never noticed that... maybe it could be a little more obvious?

Comment: @JoeHobbit, you should have gotten a notification with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user when you passed 1000 rep

Comment: @Garrett You are correct that I received a notification, which I didn't fully investigate. I was meaning to point out that the "established user" profiles being pop-out is something I haven't noticed before and could be a little more obvious-perhapse by always being popped out instead of hover-over.

Comment: @JoeHobbit Always-expanded user cards sound dangerously close to the typical low information density web forum layout that SO was specifically designed to avoid.

Comment: @blahdiblah I should have suggested including the users web-url in their small-box instead of displaying the expanded box.