# Suggested edit review should show custom rejection reasons

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

Somewhat similar to [Show other users' votes in suggested edit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215791/show-other-users-votes-in-suggested-edit-review), but rather more limited: **when Rejecting an edit**, not only the *count* of custom rejection reasons but **the actual text of the reasons should be shown**, IMO. Just now I [wrongly accepted a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8101018) on SO that tidied some code in a trivially correct and substantially superior way because it looked perfectly legitimate and I couldn't understand why anyone would bother with a custom rejection reason. As it turned out, it was code *in a question*, of course.

In this case, the rejection reason correctly identified the problem, and had I seen it, I would have been reminded of that aspect I had neglected to check.

Comment: Can you post a link to the edit you think you incorrectly accepted? The reject reason from other people should be irrelevant to your evaluation - they may have it totally wrong.

Comment: @slugster: Sure, but I'm already used to dealing with potentially unreliable previous review opinions anyway, since reject reason *counts* are already shown, and auto-comments from LQRQ are too. (And I'm on record as detesting the abominable accuracy of the latter.) I think it's fairly plain that the other reviewer was perfectly correct.