# Link Zk forum (account) to Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks

I have an Zk forum account(I see also lot of other people here and there).

I'm very active on that forum but I can't show here any of mine reputation earned there.

Could this also be linked or not?

Comment: Zk forum? Well, it's not part of SE, so no.

Comment: I know its not part of SE (otherwise it wouldn't be a problem) :)

Comment: You can link to any other profiles of yours in your "about me" field, as you already do in your SO profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the User Card popup work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work)

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch @gnat? Am I missing something particularly relevant?

Comment: @Bart you missing that asker will get the link to their zk-profile shown to anyone in user card if they get to 1K reputation. If they additionally raise a feature request to zk-forum maintainers to clone SE flair functionality, they will even be able to show their up-to-date "karma" to all readers of profile page (click mine for example to see me bragging with combined flair there, idea is pretty simple)

Comment: Ah, when including it in their "about me" field. That's true @gnat. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well thx for the aid, as marked as duplicate I will delete the question, I also want to keep the forum clean :). (well if I can delete it after the mod attention, lol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to http://forum.zkoss.org/questions/?

While that might look like SO/SE, it's not part of the network. So no, there is no way to combine accounts or transfer reputation. It's most likely using one of [the available clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

As Pëkka stated, you could mention it in your profile, and perhaps link to your account over there. (Do they have "flair"? If so, you could of course include that). But that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: Yes I'm referring to that forum.  I did put now the link in mine profile to there.