# Show user cards when hovering over name

Tags: feature-request, user-card

[User cards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work) work when the cursor hovers on a shaded user's avatar. (i.e. user with the Established User privilege who filled their About Me section.)

I would prefer it appeared when hovering over the user's display name too. This is because I tend to click the name to reach the user profile. The user card should act like a preview for the profile I'm considering visiting.

> [image: screenshot of name]

I propose we add this functionality to the names, as well as the avatars.

Comment: Don't click that user link, it leads to doom!

Comment: ..or it could lead to a shaken and not stirred martini ;)

Answer (score 4):

You definitely have a good point there, since the name and the gravatar links to the user's profile they both should trigger the expansion of the user card.

I also share your oppinion that it is more intuitive to hover over the name rather than the picture, since we are all used to navigate via text-links over the last decades of surfing through the www.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this. On community wiki posts, you can't view the hovercard, so it would make sense to make the text expand rather than the image. I originally thought it was the text that made the hovercard, simply because it seems more normal for it to be what makes the hovercard show up.

Answer (score -2):

I would make an argument against that. Links are not buttons, or images. A user expects a link to go somewhere. Having that link move itself when you hover over it breaks user's expectations and can lead to frustration.

Comment: It's not moving anywhere. The expanded user card will be like the tag popup. The link will still be clickable exactly as before.