# When did the SE flair url change?

Tags: support, status-completed, flair

All my emails now have a broken image. :(

Is it possible to restore the old urls for people who had them and allow us to use the new one from now on?

My old flair looked like:

[image: old flair]

`https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/f2f937b2b1d34d5a83e8649a1a8cd196.png`

My new flair looks like:

[image: new flair]

`https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/59521.png`

Comment: Well that makes it much easier to get someone's flair, you just need their user ID.  Change makes sense, but breaking links sucks :(

Comment: Serves you right for using html signatures in your email! :)

Comment: Did you have any accounts merged?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I did, but don't want my old emails broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guid-based flair urls are supposed to still work: they should redirect to the new url. But in certain unfortunate circumstances, users' *guids* can change – one of the reasons we've mostly moved away from our guid-based association system. In this case, your guid changed, which broke your old (deprecated) guid-based flair url.

However, for situations such as these, we've introduced a mapping of old-to-new guids, which we'll update whenever users specifically request that old flair urls be restored. So, https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/f2f937b2b1d34d5a83e8649a1a8cd196.png works again now.

Comment: I see, so *Stack Exchange employees get special treatment*.. SO UNFAIR

Comment: @Jeff, I hope there's some nicer employee benefits than a flair! ;-) That said, Emmett, just curious: is the old GUID really mapped to another GUID, and then redirected to the current short numbers? Isn't it just a mapping from GUID to short number directly?

Answer (score 2):

Given the URL you posted, I assume your old profile URL (without `/flair` but with dashes) then was https://stackexchange.com/users/f2f937b2-b1d3-4d5a-83e8-649a1a8cd196. But that doesn't work either (anymore?).

My old profile URL was https://stackexchange.com/users/c7405720-530d-49ac-baa9-f5145a2ced58 which redirects to the short URL just fine right now. Though I never used any flair: when I manually create a flair URL from that, using the format of the URL you posted, then that works just fine too: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/c7405720530d49acbaa9f5145a2ced58.png.

The same for some other old URLs [I know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108167/old-network-profile-guid-urls-might-redirect-to-wrong-user): [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/86d37599-c894-4366-8a0f-ae8727db7e13)/[flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/86d37599c89443668a0fae8727db7e13.png) and [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/d2814e0f-92a0-43b3-baf8-38c01d486fe3)/[flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/d2814e0f92a043b3baf838c01d486fe3.png).

So, it might only apply to you, or some users?

Comment: Ahh good find, it's probably because my guid changed at some point and I just didn't notice it until now.

Comment: Okay, let's hope a developer can (and is willing to) add another mapping from old to new, for the GUID that is no longer is use? (Sometimes a ♦ needs some extra care! `;-)`)

Comment: Ha, @Nick, so it was fixed indeed! :-)